# Create RSS feed (a Podcast) from a folder in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-7, itunes, rss, podcasts

I have Windows 7 with IIS7.5 installed, PHP working, and IIS Media Services. I would like to set up a *watched* folder, where I will be putting mp3s recorded daily from another utility, so that when it detects a new file it will generate a podcast feed (a RSS) that I subscribe to in my iTunes. Essentially I want to create my own podcast, from my home web server, to listen on my own iPhone as a podcast, automatically from a watched folder where I *drop* MP3s into.

Any help appreciated, hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

The following Quora question (asked by me) solved my problem, thanks:

["Podcasting: Can I create a podcast feed from a *watched* local folder in my PC?"](https://www.quora.com/Podcasting/Can-I-create-a-podcast-feed-from-a-*watched*-local-folder-in-my-PC?__snids__=17484868#comment312373)